# The set on which a convex function has affine sections.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is a real-valued convex function over an open interval $U$ contained in $\mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is not strictly convex over $U$, then we can prove that there is an $x$ and $y$ distinct from $U$ and real constants $m$ and $b$ such that
$$f(t)=mt+b$$
for every $t$ between both $x$ and $y$. However, consider the set below
$$\mathcal{C}=\{[x,y]\subseteq U: f \text{ is affine on the interval } [x,y]\}$$
The question is

> Is the union of all intervals in $\mathcal{C}$ a closed set?

Assuming that $f$ is differentiable, we know that $f'$ is increasing. And since derivatives have the intermediate value property, we can change the question in this case to:

> Is the union of all nontrivial, closed intervals where a (weakly) increasing, continuous function is constant a closed set?

If $f$ is twice differentiable, then the question becomes

> Is the zero set of a nonnegative function which has the intermediate value property a closed set?

If we know that $f''$ is continuous, then this is equivalent to the claim that $\{x\in U: f''(x)=0\}$ is closed. But at this point, this is a triviality. I'm interested in any of the three more interesting questions above. Of course, having the intermediate value property doesn't make you a derivative, so free use of being a derivative is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first two questions is no. For example, the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is constant on closed intervals like $[1/3, 2/3]$, $[1/9, 2/9]$, [7/9, 8/9], etc. The union of these intervals is dense in $[0,1]$ since its complement is a subset of the Cantor set. Yet, it is not all of the interval; in fact, the complement of the union of all of these intervals is equal to the Cantor set minus the "endpoints" (rational points of the form $k/3^m$), and there are only countably many endpoints.

A simpler example could be constructed with the intervals of constancy being $[1/(2 n+1), 1/(2n)]$, and the function being  linear in between.

Comment: That was my last sentence lol